# Can't boot with openchrome driver

Tags: openchrome

So I'm trying to get an older system that has an integrated VIA graphics chipset.  It's supported directly by the openchrome driver, which I installed from the repo.

The driver requires setting up xorg.conf, which I did following the manpage instructions

However, when it boots the desktop shows up and becomes garbled, then returns shortly thereafter.  I think what' happening is the driver is crashing and it's defaulting to the VESA driver, as that's what's loaded when I call lshw from the commandline.

Anyway, I'm not sure where to begin troubleshooting.  I looked through the syslog, but nothing stood out to me.

I have a 32-but linux install and I've checked Xorg.0.log for errors and noted:

[drm] Failed to open DRM device for pci:0000:01:00.0: No such file or directory

dmesg returns the following:

pci 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: setting as boot VGA device
pci 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: VGA device added: decodes=io+mem,owns=io+mem,locks=none
pci 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: bridge control possible

then later:

pci 0000:01:00.0: Video device with shadowed ROM at [mem 0x000c0000-0x000dffff]

So the PCI address is valid...

Comment: Possible off-topic question.  We support Ubuntu and official flavors, and you haven't told us what Ubuntu (or flavor) you are trying to get running. I'd also suggest (beyond the Ubuntu release information) you provide `sudo lshw -c video`  (to list-hardware of video class as detected by kernel)

Comment: Ah, nevermind.  I run a bunch of distros, depending on the machine.  Lubuntu 18.10 didn't work, so I tried MX to see if I could get past the error.